# What are the differences between Spring Boot and Eclipse Scout? Is it not nearly the same?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, eclipse-scout

Based on my research it is nearly the same. They are both frameworks to create java based microservices and web apps. Eclipse scout is more based in business applications? When does it make sense to use one or the other?

Answer (score 0):

You use Spring Boot when you want to use the entire Spring ecosystem and benefit from its vast community and documentation to rapidly develop enterprise applications, microservices or Web applications. Eclipse Scout is best suited when you need to develop complex business applications with specific features, such as business workflows or customized user interfaces.